# How to push navigate to a new Widget when remote notification is received?

Tags: push-notification, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I'm trying to achieve in my app is when a user receives a push notification the app will push a new widget. I get correctly the notification data but I can't make it work.

This is the listener for notifications

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
        _manageNotificationData(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
         _manageNotificationData(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
        _manageNotificationData(message);
      },
    );
```

My payload is

```
data: {
       "id" : "Id for notification state",
       "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK","
       "orderId": "SomeId"
      }
```

```
void _manageNotificationData(Map<String,dynamic> message){

 //When the user receives a notification, a new widget will appear so that he can rate another user

  if(message["id"] == 1){

  //This data is printed in the console
  print(message["orderId"]);

  //this is not working
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
    RateProfessionalWidget(
    orderId: message["orderId"])
    ),
  );
  }

}
```

I guess this will not work because I calling Navigator.push in the main file but in this file is the only place I have access to the notification data. How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your app (the thing that you `runApp()`) is a `StatefulWidget`, and in its state create a `GlobalKey`

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'navKey');
```

When you create your `MaterialApp` pass it the key

```
  child: MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
```

In your app you can now use `navigatorKey.currentState.push()` etc